# <a href onClick="return false;"> not working in Safari/iOS?

Tags: html, ios

I have this code in my page:

```
<a href onClick="return false;">Press me!</a>
```

The link is placed inside a span with a useful onClick event.

Now, in Chrome and Firefox this works perfectly. The link is clicked, the useful event is executed and everybody's happy. In iOS (iPhone and iPad) using the default Safari browser, this fails miserably - after the link is clicked the whole page is reloaded and the useful event is never executed.

I also tried

```
<a href="#" onClick="return false;">Press me!</a>
```

Which I understood to be the wrong way of doing this. In Chrome and Firefox it works well, but in iOS' Safari it jumped back to the beginning of the page (but it DID execute the useful event, so in a sense it was better).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, it seems like a bug in iOS browser JS implementation (maybe create a minimal code to demonstrate it?).

A simple workaround would be to replace the `<a href...>` with `<span style="cursor:pointer;">`.

Comment: This is not the solution I was hoping for, but it seems indeed to be a bug in iOS, and the workaround worked.

Answer (score 7):

You can set `href="#"`, and I'm noticing the same jumping to the top of the page. `#` is an in-page anchor, which I believe refers to the top of the page. I'm not clear on the defined behavior for that. But alas, you want to cancel it.

In the iPhone 5.0.1 Simulator, combining both cancelation methods works and doesn't scroll to the top. This is my complete `test.html` file. It works in the simulator, Chrome and OS X Safari.

```
<div style="height: 1000px; background-color: blue;"></div>
<a href="#" onClick="event.preventDefault(); return false;">Poke it!</a>
<div style="height: 1000px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

For the record, removing the `event.preventDefault();` duplicates your bug.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about using preventDefault.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried binding the element purely from javascript?

```
<a href="#" id="nogo">Foo</a>

document.getElementById('nogo').onclick = function(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: This is a problematic solution since there are many such links, and they are created dynamically by a larger system (phpbb, for that matter; the link is for displaying spoiler text).

Comment: Ah fair enough, wasn't specified so couldn't have guess. can you use jquery at all? then you can bind them all with one command even newly created one.

Comment: I can do some hacking, but I'd prefer to stay within the rules, i.e. supplying a html code that will replace the spoiler tags in messages, without playing with viewtopic.php itself. I didn't specify the context because it seemed to me this is a problem of me not understanding something basic about the way links work.

Comment: I don't think you're able to do that in that case. You can only use preventDefault return false er a # in the href to stop the page from loading.